# Quadric in 3 dimensions infinite cylinder but in 4 a glome

Tags: geometry, quadratic-forms

I am walking in circles with the question why wolframalpha gives me as geometric description of
$$(x-y)^2+(x-z)^2+(z-y)^2-14=0$$
as the infinite cylinder and of
$$(x-y)^2+(x-z)^2+(x-u)^2+(z-y)^2+(u-y)^2+(z-u)^2-30=0$$
a glome, i.e., 3 sphere. The first is unbounded and the second is compact but their defining equations are just extensions to the dimension of the first plus one.

How is that possible? I do not manage to see it at all.

Comment: one thing you know is that, given a point $(x,y,z,u)$  that works, you can add the same arbitrary value $t$  to all four variables and still have a point that works. So the second is also a cylinder.

Comment: so, for a familiar surface, demand the variables to sum to zero; This is the intersection of your set with $x+y+z+u=0$  As a basis of this 3-plane you may take $(-1,1,0,0) / \sqrt 2,  (-1,-1,2,0)/ \sqrt 6 , (-1,-1,-1,3) / \sqrt {12} $  and see what happens

Comment: @WillJagy what would that cylinder look like? Something like $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I'm suspicious of that, as the   4-D Hessian has eigenvalues $(2,2,-2,-2).$  I would bet on a hyperboloid,  either one sheet or two.  The careful approach is to use my orthonormal basis for the 3-plane $x+y+z+u=0,$   call them $v_1, v_2, v_3$   and new coefficients $(p,q,r)$  and find out  the relation among $p,q,r$  when $pv_1 + q v_2 + r v_3$  is in your set with $30.$

Comment: I did it, came out $4(p^2 + q^2 + r^2) = 30,$  so your guess was correct.